# MaaS - Fatal Error inserting ipmi_si

Tags: virtualbox, maas

I'm currently trying to install a node with MaaS (virtualbox)

So after I've setup the Maas Controller, I start a second virtual machine
with pxe-boot. The installation process runs for some time and then always stops 
at the following error message

`FATAL: Error inserting ipmi_si (lib/modules/3.2.0-31-generic/kernel/drivers/char/ipmi/ipmi_si.ko): No such device`

Has anybody some advice as to how this can be fixed?

regards Sandro

Answer (score 7):

The failure that you see is because this is a virtual machine. The `ipmi_si` related stuff will only work on real hardware, so the error doesn't really affect your case scenario and you don't really need a fix for it.

A good idea would be if you were able to post the output of `/proc/cpuinfo` so that we can make sure that the module above is not loaded on Virtual Box VM's.

Comment: For some reason, later that day, the commission-process finished. I was playing around with it, but couldn't really reproduce it.

Anyway, here's the output of /proc/cpuinfo:  
processor : 0
vendor_id : GenuineIntel
cpu family : 6
model  : 42
model name : Intel(R) Core(TM) i5-2415M CPU @ 2.30GHz
stepping : 7
cpu MHz  : 2276.489
cache size : 6144 KB
fpu  : yes
fpu_exception : yes
cpuid level : 5
wp  : yes

Comment: flags  : fpu vme de pse tsc msr pae mce cx8 apic sep   mtrr pge mca cmov pat pse36 clflush mmx fxsr sse sse2 syscall nx   rdtscp lm constant_tsc rep_good nopl pni monitor ssse3 lahf_lm  
bogomips : 4552.97  
clflush size : 64  
cache_alignment : 64  
address sizes : 36 bits physical, 48 bits virtual  
power management:

Comment: Would be great if that would work with Virtualbox. I was trying to install OpenStack with Juju

Comment: Unfortunately, IPMI won't work on any virtualization technology. Based on your output, I can't see anything that would tell me that the host is a Virtual Box VM, which would allow me to prevent it from trying to modprobe ipmi_si. Either way, this won't affect how MAAS works.